# Unable to set SESSION CHARSET to UTF16 in BTEQ

Tags: teradata

I have a file that I need to execute within BTEQ that is formatted in UTF16 with BOM. However I get the following error when I try to set the CHARSET before running the file:

```
.SET SESSION CHARSET 'UTF16';
 *** Error: SET SESSION CHARSET UTF16 is not allowed.
```

I can set this to UTF8 and convert the file to UTF8 and it works. I also can convert the file to UTF8 without BOM and not set CHARSET the script runs. This file is system generated and I'm automating this script deployment so converting the document is not preferred.

ADDING ADDITIONAL INFO:
The input script used for my automation do not have the BOM and are generated in Powershell using the .RUN FILE option to open the file that does have the BOM.  Thus the need to do the .SET SESSION CHARSET setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start `bteq` in `utf-16` mode, use below command

```
>bteq -c utf16
```

According to teradata documentation:

> `-c` option defines the session character set encoding for a Unicode
>   session and takes an argument which can be any supported character set
>   value

It can be verified using `.show control charset` as below.

```
T e r a d a t a   B T E Q   1 6 . 0 0 . 0 0 . 0 2   f o r   W I N 3 2 .   P I D :   1 2 1 2
C o p y r i g h t   1 9 8 4 - 2 0 1 6 ,   T e r a d a t a   C o r p o r a t i o n .   A L L   R I G H T S   R E S E R V E D .
E n t e r   y o u r   l o g o n   o r   B T E Q   c o m m a n d :
.show control charset;

. s h o w   c o n t r o l   c h a r s e t ;

  [ S E T ]   S E S S I O N   C H A R S E T                 =   U T F 1 6 ;                                            
              i m p o r t / e x p o r t   e n c o d i n g   =   U T F 1 6 ;                                            
              s t d i n / s t d o u t   e n c o d i n g     =   U T F 1 6 ;
```

You can check **[invoking-bteq-to-use-unicode](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/invoking-workstation-bteq-to-use-unicode)** for details

Comment: The input script used for my automation do not have the BOM and are generated in Powershell using the .RUN FILE option to open the file that does have the BOM. Thus the need to do the .SET SESSION CHARSET setting.

Comment: I did some further testing and found the only way to get .SET SESSION CHARSET to accept 'utf16' was to modify my bteq input file to UTF16 with BOM then start as suggested.  Thank you for your help.